# scp from raspberry pi to android device not working

Tags: android, scp

I try to send text files from my raspberry pi 3 to my android phone, with the following line:

```
scp -P 2222 /mnt/extsdcard/download/sent.txt root@192.168.1.30 home/pi/test.txt
```

192.168.1.30 is my android phone's IP address.

I get this error: No such file or directory. I'm not sure that root is okay. What should be there in case of an android device, where can I see the username of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to connect to android with `ssh root@192.168.1.30`
2. try this command: `scp -P 2222 /mnt/extsdcard/download/sent.txt root@192.168.1.30:~/test.txt`

As you answer, you have not turned on ssh on `Android`, basically this is not a problem from `raspberry`. You cannot use `scp` without `ssh` enabled.

Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468053/how-can-i-communicate-with-an-android-device-via-ssh) and follow answers to how torn ssh on on `Android` device

Comment: I got this when writing 2.):

    ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.30 port 2222: Connection refused
lost connection.

I tried it with my tablet too and it did not work either:
"No route to host, lost connection"

Comment: The first one is working_

Comment: ssh root@192.168.1.30 gives me this:
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.30 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Thanks for the quick edition! As hopefully other users will use my application and it'll be likely they don't have any other application (like SSHDroid) downloaded only mine. Do you have an advice what i can use insted of SSH/SCP?

Comment: Could you show more details about what you want to do and how? As I understood you want to send file from server(`raspberry`) to client (`Android`)

Have you write some server side code? If yes, which language you used?

Comment: I now have an application which does the following: 
When I press a button in that app, that creates an ssh connection with the rpi and the rpi sends back a file. But that sending back is slow. The python script on the rpi that I run from my android device uploads the file to a cloud strorage and my app downloads it. Bluetooth connection also works but it is much slower. What method would be faster? Thanks.